# Aggregation Sum Distinct documents from array field MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a set of documents that have a field with an array of text tags. E.g.

```
{
  _id: uXFLH__St8o3NfxwMa53ig,
  tags: ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
},
{
  _id: DWbe__3fegKXBa_Ai3CGRQ,
  tags: ['foo', 'bar']
}
```

I would like to get a count of the distinct occurrences of these tags across the collection such that the output is

```
{
  "_id": "foo",
  count: 2
},
{
  "_id": "bar",
  count: 2
},
{
  "_id": "foobar",
  count: 1
}
```

I've tried aggregation (I have some complex $match steps as well), but cannot figure out what to do to get the output above. This query:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$tags", count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

produces this result:

```
{
"_id" : ['foo', 'bar']
"count" : 1.0
},
{
"_id" : ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
"count" : 1.0
}
```

Much appreciated in advance.

Comment: you are missing `$unwind` step. `{$unwind:"$tags"}` before group. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: Yeah that is it. Thanks. It is always something small. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
{
  $unwind : "$tags"
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$tags",
    count: {$sum: 1}}
}
])
```